# Running python script on background using PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

I have a python script that runs a TCP server and is running indefinitely. 
This script is working on background in my terminal:

> ```
> sudo python3 TCPServer.py &
> ```

But when I use PHP shell_exec command:

> shell_exec('sudo python3 TCPServer.py &')

It executes but waits forever. I want it to run on background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a command in background with `shell_exec`, the output must be redirected to /dev/null. Refer the [php nanual notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#118495).

```
shell_exec("python3 TCPServer.py 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/mylog 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &");
```

Comment: Thanks! What I was looking for. :)